# Show that the permutation [n, n-1,..., 2,1] has n(n-1) inversions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Show that the permutation $[n, n-1,..., 2,1]$ has $n(n-1)$ inversions

How do I show that this is true? Why isn't $(n(n-1))/2$

Comment: It would improve your question to include an explanation of _why_ you think it's $\frac12 n(n-1)$.

Comment: Some small examples illustrate the distinction.  $[2,1]$ has one inversion, not $2\cdot 1$.  $[3,2,1]$ has three inversions, not $3\cdot 2$.  Some additional discussion is [here](http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~paxton/algorithmics/week10/Perms/statement.htm), certainly a definition of how to count inversions in a permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your permutation $\pi$, and it's elements $\pi_i$, indexed left to right. So in this case $\pi_1=n,\pi_2=n-1,\cdots \pi_n=1$. For any pair of indices $(i,j)$, with $i<j$, you have $\pi_i>\pi_j$, the definition of an inversion. Thus the number of inversions is precisely the number of pairs of indices $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ picked from numbers $1,2,\cdots,n$. The answer is $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which is the number of ways to pick two unordered elements from a list of $n$ numbers.

Comment: I know this definition, but the textbook is asking me to proof n(n-1) instead of n(n-1)/2, i feel confused..

Comment: @EvanC: It's probably a typo, unless they are counting ordered inversions, with $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ being "different."

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's what I thought. It might be typo from textbook, thanks for great expliantion